# Release Pipelines for Hundreds of SaaS tenants

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Our application is currently an ASP.NET Core application hosted on Azure and our code and pipelines are hosted on Azure Dev Ops. The app is pretty simple with just a Web Application and Azure SQL Database.

We currently have a large number of tenants that we would like to deploy to after each release.

We currently have 3 Build Pipelines (which are triggered off dev, test and master branches):
- Dev 
- Test
- Production

Where I currently get lost is on where to put the individual tenants, our current path was to make a "Release" pipeline for every tenant. Is this the best way to do this? Should we be using stages instead?

Comment: Are you using YAML or UI?

Comment: In azure devops, you can use deployment group to manage environments which related to per tenant. Or you can use Octupus to manage tenants then use extension in azure devops to achieve one pipeline with one stage and multi-tenants deployments. For personal, I would think the second one is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to why you have separate build pipelines for `dev`, `test`, and `production`.

You might consider consolidating all of your pipelines (build and release) into a single [YAML pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema). Under this approach, you'd have 1 build stage which you would capture as a [YAML stage template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) and make use of [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)/[conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to account for the variances between the various environments. Alternatively, if the build process varies widely between environments, you could have separate build stage templates for each and include the appropriate one based on branch that triggered the build.

For releases, you could capture each as a YAML template and then include them at the end of the pipeline using the new [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#deployment-job) element that has been added to the YAML schema.

Hopefully this gets you closer to a solution or at least gives you some things to think about.

Comment: Yeah, I think I may be as confused as you are! I think sometimes old habits from using the UI in the past over the years. Thanks for the references, I am going to look those over and see if I can find a way to put more details to ask the question better.